# Loading kernel in a bootsector

Tags: kernel, nasm, bootloader

I'm very new and confused with this bootloader. I use QEMU bootloader. I'm really having problems with implementing how to load kernel or some .asm file in NASM. I already implemented my kernel file and I want to load it to my bootsector file.

I just follow what the internet has to say with building a bootsector and I came up with this:

```
[BITS 16]    
[ORG 0x7C00]

mov [bootdrv], dl   ;put drive number
        ;disable interrupt, set stack, enable interrupt                         
cli                     
mov ax, 0x9000          
mov ss, ax              
mov sp, 0               
sti         

...
*some code here nothing to do with loading
...

.load_kernel:       
    call read_kernel            ; Load stuff from the bootdrive
    jmp dword KERNEL_SEGMENT:0

read_kernel:
    push ds               
    .reset:
      mov ax, 0               ;reset disk
      mov dl, [bootdrv]       ;drive to reset
      int 13h                
      jc .reset               ;try again if fail
    pop ds

.read:
    *this is where I became confused and lost. I read that you should 
     locate your kernel and pass around using the bootdrv(drive number)
     and return. I can't seem to understand.
```

Any answer would be very helpful cuz I'm really lost.

Answer (score 1):

You can place your kernel anywhere you want. 
The easiest solution for you is to fill the rest of bootloader´s sector by zeroes and continue writing your code in the same file.

```
; your code
...

; bootloader has 512 bytes, so...

; fill up to 510 bytes with zeroes and ...
times 510-($-$$) db 0 

; place the boot signature on the end
dw 0xAA55
```

For loading, you can use function `2` of interrupt `0x13`.

```
.read:
    push es ; save ES if there's something important in it

    ; load the "kernel" at KERNEL_SEGMENT:0
    mov ax, KERNEL_SEGMENT
    mov es, ax
    xor bx, bx

    ; your kernel will have 512 bytes (1 sector) for now
    mov al, 0x1

    ; get the saved drive number back to DL
    mov dl, [bootdrv]

    mov dh, 0x0 ; head 0
    mov cl, 0x2 ; start reading from 2nd sector

    ; read
    int 0x13

    pop es ; restore ES

    ret ; return and continue after call instruction
```

Comment: nice, seems so simple. i can understand little by little. reset has been implemented well and stack is set well. however, it still doesn't load my kernel file. what seems to be the problem? can you teach me more of this. i can edit my bootsector as a whole nasm code if you need clearer info.

Comment: Try to use some debugging environment.