# Load kernel from bootloader

Tags: kernel, bootloader

So, I have a kernel compiled with gcc & linked to a bin with ld. I also have a bootloader compiled with NASM. I'd like to load kernel.bin (which is on my ISO) from bootloader.bin & jump to the loaded code.

(I don't want to use grub/any other already made bootloader that's good for my mental health).

Comment: If you link an ELF to a binary you miss the point of an ELF file. I'd recommend compiling an elf with GCC and parsing the ELF file from assembly then jumping to the entry_point. It is pretty simple since you only need to parse the program header and the entry_point in the main header. ELF files are made to work with virtual adressing. Depending on how far you want to go, you'd better set up paging before jumping to an elf file.

Comment: In related questions there are some that explicitly answer your question like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059483/loading-kernel-in-a-bootsector?rq=1